# Alternative to intrincate sentence

Tags: synonyms

I've written this sentence, but it seems a little bit intricate.

> This leads to imbalance data, a well-known problem to which the
>   inference algorithms are sensitive.

I don't know how to make a sentence with the same meaning but less intricate. Maybe you can give some advice or alternatives.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I see nothing wrong with the sentence as given.

Comment: you should change _imbalance_ to _imbalanced_ and remove _the_, but otherwise it looks good. I would probably also substitute _sensitive_ for _prone_ (but sensitive is fine).

Comment: I don't see why you want to have one big sentence with all this information tied up in subordinate clauses. If you want to state all this, use a different sentence for each concept, and link the sentences up into a paragraph so that their connections are obvious. This is not really a grammatical problem.

Comment: That's also true. Could you give an example? @JohnLawler

Comment: An example of what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence as it stands makes sense apart from 'imbalance data'.

This could be changed to either **'imbalanced data'** or **'data imbalance'**

The use of 'sensitive' does however imply two meanings. 
Either the algorithms are adversely affected by the data imbalance, or the algorithms are finely adjusted to deal with the effects of the data imbalance. Currently the sentence does not specify whether the algorithmic sensitivity is the problem or the solution to the problem.

I believe that clarifying this aspect would make the sentence more direct and specific, and seem less intricate.

If the influence of the data imbalance is negative then the following would be an alternative:

> This leads to data imbalance, a well-known problem to which the
>   inference algorithms are susceptible.

If the influence of the data imbalance is more neutral then the sentence could be written as follows:

> This leads to data imbalance, a well-known problem which affects the
>   inference algorithms.

If the influence of the data imbalance is resolved by the algorithms then the sentence could be written as follows.

> This leads to the well-known problem of data imbalance, for which the
>   inference algorithms account.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer @Manhatton. Your analysis is perfect. The right meaning is "the data imbalance is negative", so I'm choosing the first alternative, but certainly all of them are useful.